# ES6 Import Scenario

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There are multiple way to import modules. What is the difference between `import {House}` and `import House`?

[image]

Comment: first one is a named import and second one is default import

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import is a good place to read about this

Comment: Please could you put relevant information from the scenario within the question, rather than as a linked image? That will make it easier for people to see what you're asking about.

Comment: What would be the answer for attached images for Type1 and Type2

Answer (score 3):

There are two way to import in ES6 module, based on the export option.

1. **Named Import**

```
//filename - simple.js

export function Simple() {}

import {Simple} from "./simple.js"
```

2. **Default Import**

```
//filename - simple.js
export default Class Simple {}


import Simple from "./simple.js"
```

For more, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

**UPDATE**
You can also export both from a single file and import them. Important caveat here is there can be only one default export in a module.

```
//filename - simple.js

export function Simple1() {}
export default function Simple2() { }

import Simple2, { Simple1 } from "./simple.js"
```

Comment: Will both will get impoerted as import {Simple} from "./simple.js"

1 - export function Simple(){
    return "lamborghini";
}

AND

2 - function Simple(){
    return "lamborghini";
}

export default Simple;

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `import {House}` is used to import specific, named imports like `import {foo, bar} from '/modules/my-module.js';`

while the syntax `import House` is used to import default exports like `import myDefault from '/modules/my-module.js';`

> As one can see that we can mix these two. For example, this is also a valid import
>   `import myDefault, {foo, bar} from '/modules/my-module.js';`

to read more checkout [Mozilla developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).